# Blocking specific senders in outlook 2010 (blocking other than sending to junk)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to block a partiuclar email address in outlook 2010 so that the email bounces and it does not end up in junk

thanks Evan

Answer (score 1):

This article has a [solution](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2010/07/21/quick-rule-creation-in-outlook-2010.aspx)

1. Select your account in the **Navigation Pane** and click **Inbox**.
2. Select a message from the **sender** you would like to block.
3. Using the ribbon, select the **Home** tab and then click **Rules**.
4. Click **Always Move Messages From:**
5. Choose **Trash** as your destination folder

Email from this sender will now automatically route to the trash. "Bouncing" email is a server function and not something you can replicate using an email client.